# What are some hacks to improve FPS that one can apply for Unity Games?

Tags: unity-games

There are lots of Unity Games that lag on medium powerful systems.

As an example, "The Signal From Tölva" - I'm running this game at 1280 X 900, with everything either disabled or set to the lowest values. And in spite of that I'm getting an FPS of ~15. Looking at Steam's forum this seems to be a common experience.

Yet, I can run Skyrim at maxed out settings with 1920 X 1080.

Another example is Everreach: Project Eden, a game from 2019, 2 years back but it runs with 10-15 FPS. Looking at Steam's forums there are again lots of people with this experience.

So there are lots of Unity games that run normally on one hardware but are pretty laggy on another.

What are some hacks/settings that I can apply to Unity games (generally) in order to improve their frame rates?

Comment: Are you purely interested in *average* frame count (smooth, just too slow), or are you struggling with highly variable frame time (stuttering)?

Comment: Note that (the original) Skyrim was released 6 years before The Signal From Tölva. I suspect that the quality of graphics play a roll here which may lead to insufficient amount of VRAM.

Comment: If I google 'Everreach: Project Eden' I see a game from december 2019... Did you mean Project Eden perhaps?

Comment: @chebureki It's the average frame count. A highly variable frame time might usually be more to do with game optimization than generic solutions in which case this question wouldn't be of any use.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I stand corrected. I've updated the question.